# how do i add this row to this table without effecting auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

right, i have a table with the fields: id, title, description, keywords and link. In the table i have hundreds of websites for a search engine. I am struggling though in this section. The id is set to auto-increment and i would like to be able to add a line of code that embeds itself in the table, in the middle somewhere, with the id tag (auto-increment) to adjust in the whole table. So if i was to add 'Google' to id '81', 81 will go to 82 to adjust to it. is there a way to do that with SQL?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would 80 become 79? Wouldn't you just want to increment everything starting at 81?

Comment: I am also getting that from what he wants to accomplish.

Comment: Don't treat a database the same as you would an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Identity column is not expected to behave that way.

Comment: i'm sorry then. but do u get what i am trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the point though? How will you benefit by doing this?

Comment: The id column is rows' *unique* identifier. If you change the id of a row, you change the row's identity, it becomes something else. It's like changing everyone's bank account number because the got a new customer with a name before yours in the alphabet. If you need  number that indicates an order, create a new field and don't make it auto-increment - Than you can do what you like to it.  *(Wanting to do what you have asked is actually a demonstration of a mis-understanding as to what that field should and should not be used for, a mis-understanding of relational database design principles.)*

Comment: Understand it yes. Agree in anyway shape or form that it's a good idea, worth the effort and the risk absolutely not. Why do you want to do this, it's a bunch of hideous bugs you are about to find.

Comment: Does the entity actually need to be embedded in the middle of the _database_, or do you just want to display it to the user in the middle of the table?

Comment: my search engine is ranked on id, so if keywords clash the higher id wins. If i say want to add a new site, a popular site i have not added, it would have to go quite high in the mysql table. is there a way to neaty embed it? have u another idea?

Comment: Ideally you want a 'rank' column which denotes the rank of identical entries.

Comment: @user1582899 - As in my comment and a few others, create a field specifically for that ordering.  Then you can change the values in that field without any unexpected implications.  It even gives you freedoms like storing the `popularity_score` which may not be `1` or `2` but rather `68.23598` and `69.1234`, then you simply `ORDER BY` that field.

Comment: how could i do this? could you show me in some code please. :)

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is not really meant to be used the way you want to use it. It is mainly just a reference to any one row in your table for the main purpose of being used as a foreign key in other tables. If you want to have your rows sorted in a certain way you should have another column that you can influence.

EDIT:

But now just in case you really want to renumber and your autoincrement ID is not used in any other table for reference and nobody is currently using the table you can

- remove the ID column
- add the ID column without auto_increment
- update the ID for 'Google' as 81
- modify the ID column to be auto_increment again

Maybe like this

```
alter table mywebsitetable drop column id;

alter table mywebsitetable add column id bigint;

update mywebsitetable set id = 81 where websitename = 'Google';

... do more numbering as you like and this does give numbers to all the other rows:

alter table ify.test modify id bigint primary key auto_increment;
```

And if you want to keep the all the IDs then you can even add another column to save the ID column, copy them over with an two update statements. One update for the IDs before 81 and another one after the 81 one where it is incrementing the ID. Then you add the drop and add the column, copy over the IDs from the save column, drop the save column, add google and switch on auto_increment again. But this will take long when your table is large and I do not recommend this because as I said before, auto increment is not meant for ordering or as the mentioned in that one comment, auto_increment is not supposed to be treated like lines in a spread sheet.